# Using Method from Activity Class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, extends

I am extending BroadcastReceiver class but in the given function I need to use **getIntent()** function which is a part of **Activity class**.
How should I use this function since I will only be able to extend just one Class.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

AudioManager audioControl;
Bundle extras;
int startHour,startMinute;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    Date d = new Date();
    String day = sdf.format(d);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    audioControl = (AudioManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
        startHour = extras.getInt("startHour");
        startMinute = extras.getInt("startMinute");
    }

    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if(day.equals("Thursday")){
        if(hour==startHour){
            if(minute==startMinute){
                audioControl.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT** : My main Class:

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("day", "Tuesday");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Settings.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    alarmRepeat();
}
  public void alarmRepeat(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Well, which activity's intent do you want to get?

Comment: be aware that to compare strings you have to use equals

Comment: @immibis..I am passing Intent from my mainActivity where I get the startHour and startMinute integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Just check your onReceive() method

```
@Override                                      
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                                              ^^^^^
    //you already have an instance of Intent object
    //just use it like this.
    Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use getIntent()-method. The Intent will be provided as Parameter in your onReceive-method.

Instead of using:

```
extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

you could simply use

```
extras = intent.getExtras();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.string");
intent.putExtra("startHour", ******); 
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your class AlarmReceiver, change

```
extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

to

```
extras = intent.getExtras();
if(extras.equals("my.action.string")){
     String shour= intent.getExtras().getString("startHour");

}
```

and in menifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AlramReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- and your existing actions  -->
        <action android:name="my.action.string" />
        <!-- and some more actions if you want -->
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Activity** doesn't implement interfaces of **Serializable** and **Parcelable**, so you can't pass it as a parameter of Intent, namely, you can't call like this:

```
intent.putExtra(string, Activity);
```

Meanwhile, when you register a BroadcastReceiver, Intent has been passed as a paramter. At the same time, you can get it which is exactly the second parameter in receive(Context, Intent) of BroadcastReceiver.

```
@Override                                      
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //intent is exactly the Intent you passed,into which you can put your startHour and startMinute integer values.
    int startHour = intent.getInt("startHour");
    int startMinute = intent.getInt("startMinute");
}
```

Comment: I used as You said but it dosn't work when I pass anything. See the edit.